# Live modification/creation of file/data with pure php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, database

For example
[image]

```
[['Inflammation'],['Noxious stimuli cause resident effector cells to secrete cytokines<br>Cytokines ↑ vascular dilation & permeability<br>Calor, dolor, penuria, rubor & tumor ensue.',],["Haematology","Immunology","Leukocyte","Cytokine"]],

[[TITLE/NAMES],[DATA],[TAGS]]
```

How can I have multiple users be able to edit this, similar to google docs; if an edit function is ran by the user.

Is this possible with pure php?
Are there any other ways to do this without the use of a database?
So far everything is being done via js/jquery; I am open to alternatives; though am looking for the simplest possible way.

Comment: At a very high level you would use JavaScript to track user interactions with the document and replay them to all "connected" users. You can do this with native technologies, but in the past I just used a service such as [Pusher](https://pusher.com/)

Comment: I'm attempting to keep it stupid simple

Comment: "similar to Google docs" is very complicated. Simple is tried and true HTML forms, with people occasionally overwriting each other’s data. You need to decide where you want to be on that spectrum, in relation to the effort.

Comment: How about one human per piece of data but still real time?

Comment: You are back to my first comment then. You need to quantify “data” and explain it to JavaScript (jQuery, TypeScript, etc.). You also need to explain “change”. Text fields are arguably obvious, but do you want to send every keystroke, or wait for someone to be “done”. Then, you need to get that data to everyone. Two web browsers on the internet cannot talk to each other without a server “doing something”. But checkout Pusher, you can build a PoC with just a couple of lines. They also have a 4 part tutorial on building a spreadsheet, but that is more advanced.